# Sftp from SharpSSH and public key

Tags: c#, sftp, sharpssh

I am using SharpSSH's Sftp class to upload files.  Someone has requested that I enable RSA authentication.  I can't find an info how how to do this.  What do I need to do in order to support public key authentication in SharpSSH?

All I currently do is this

```
 ftp = new Sftp(config.SftpServer, config.SftpUsername, config.SftpPassowrd);
 ftp.Connect();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to connect with an RSA I needed to create an OpenSSH format key and save it to disk. PuttyGen worked well for this. Then I simply needed to call AddIdentityFile with that file like so

```
 ftp = new Sftp(config.SftpServer, config.SftpUsername, config.SftpPassowrd);
 ftp.AddIdentityFile("file");
 ftp.Connect();
```

Comment: Great !! I guess u mispelled the ftp object in the second line.